# CrystalReportViwer no muestra el informe

Tags: asp, crystal-reports

Hola estoy usando CrystalReports en ASP .NET con VS2017 y cuando trato de visualizar el informe este se ve en el html source pero no en el navegador, alguien me oriente...

Codigo VB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista Navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista en el inspector HTML:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás mostrando, a través de un iframe o cómo?

Comment: Lo estoy mostrando en un control CR:CrystalReportViwer directamente en el formulario.

Comment: ¿El error ocurre en tu PC o en un servidor? ¿te arroja algún error la consola de tu explorador, por ejemplo que no carga estilos?

Comment: No, la consola esta limpia.

Comment: Encontre la solucion agregando la carpeta aspnet_client al root del proyecto, no tenia idea de esto ya que estoy acostumbrado a ms report builder, gracias por la guia

Comment: Excelente, podrías agregarlo como respuesta :)

Comment: también tengo el problema que no visualiza el reporte. Donde encuentro esta carpeta para copiar aspnet_client

Comment: Esta en tu disco en la carpeta inetpub/wwwroot